Negative Voltage at Transistor bases in my Differential Amplifier
I am supposed to calculate the differential input resistance but the voltage at the base of the transistor is negative so according to my formula I will have a negative resistance which is most likely wrong. My simulation is in transient mode.

You haven’t shown your formula, please add it to the question so we can see what you are doing.  I believe you will find that the polarity of the current will be such that the negatives will cancel and you’ll end up with a positive value for resistance.

Does a resistor have a negative resistance when the voltage across it is negative?

I have edited the post with the full requirements

You may be confusing DC conditions with the AC amplitudes required by Table 6?

How would these differ from the displayed values? Am I supposed to change a setting? This is the first time I am using this software so I am really lost

@Cezar Please write a specific question

You're pulling the emitters to -12V, and the DC path from the base(s) to ground is 100K.  In that configuration, the emitter will be pulled down until the collector supplies enough current to balance the network on the emitters.  In order to get the collector current, some base current must be supplied.  In your case that's about 6uA.
That current passing through your 100K resistors causes a drop of about 0.6V.  (This is coincidentally similar to, but unrelated to, the B-E drop.)
So that negative current is the bias that Rv1, RE, T1, and T2 must draw from ground to -12V in order for the collectors to conduct to equilibrium.

Thank you for your answer, I have edited the post with the formula that I am supposed to use that is causing me problems (negative resistance), the parameters of Vin are Voff=0 Vampl=100m and Freq=1k. Can you please help me figure this out, as I don’t think this is the intended behaviour of the circuit…is it?

The formula you added is for AC voltages, not DC.  Your DC input impedance is infinite due to the series cap C1.  C1 should, in a perfect world, be included with Rg in that formula as a reactance, but at 1KHz it has an impedance magnitude of about 16 ohms, so it won't affect the result much.
